# TSQL Order/Sequence groups in a query

Tags: t-sql, select, grouping, unique

I have the following data...

| uid | groupid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 |

I would like to uniquely order the groups so that I get....

| uid | groupid | newGroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 2 |
| 8 | 0 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | 2 | 3 |
| 11 | 2 | 3 |

Can anyone help me do this in SQL (SQL Server)

Comment: What does `uniquely order the groups` means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as 
(
    select * from (values 
        (1  , 0),
        (2  , 0),
        (3  , 1),
        (4  , 1),
        (5  , 1),
        (6  , 1),
        (7  , 0),
        (8  , 0),
        (9  , 2),
        (10 , 2),
        (11 , 2))
    t([uid], [groupid])
),
cte2 as
(
    select 
        [uid], [groupid],
        newGroupId = 
            row_number() over(order by [uid]) 
            - 
            row_number() over(partition by [groupid] order by [uid])    
    from 
        cte
)
select
    [uid], [groupid],
    newGroupId = dense_rank() over(order by newGroupId) - 1
from
    cte2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach than Vadium, but another option to consider:

```
;WITH CTE_MAIN AS
(
 select * from (values 
        (1  , 0),
        (2  , 0),
        (3  , 1),
        (4  , 1),
        (5  , 1),
        (6  , 1),
        (7  , 0),
        (8  , 0),
        (9  , 2),
        (10 , 2),
        (11 , 2))
    t([uid], [groupid])
),
CTE_2 AS
(
    SELECT uid, groupid, LAG(groupid,1,-1) OVER(ORDER BY uid) LastGroupID
    FROM CTE_MAIN
)
SELECT uid, groupid, SUM(CASE WHEN GroupID <> LastGroupID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY uid) - 1 NewGroup
FROM CTE_2
```